# Uploading data from Google Sheets to BigQuery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload data from a sheet in Google sheets by using a google app script. The script works fine for uploading small sets of data, but when I want to upload like 10 000 rows, no data is uploaded to BigQuery. I tried to change Utilities.sleep time but it did not help. I also tried to change 'WRITE_APPEND' to 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'. However, none of these changes seems to help and I have no idea why the script is not working for bigger datasets.

Here is the script:

```
function upload_to_BQ() {

  var projectId = 'production';
  var datasetId = 'test_dataset';
  var tableId = 'contacts_test';
  // URL of the Google sheet
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xx';

// the name of the sheet which will be uploaded
  var sheetName = 'upload';

  // Create the table.
  var table = {
    tableReference: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId
    },
    schema: {
      fields: [
        {name: 'full_name', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'email', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'company', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'country', type: 'STRING'},
        {name: 'uploaded', type: 'DATE'}

      ]
    }
  };

  // WRITE_TRUNCATE: 
  // WRITE_APPEND: 
  // WRITE_EMPTY: 
  var writeDispositionSetting = 'WRITE_APPEND';

  try {BigQuery.Tables.get(projectId, datasetId, tableId)}
  catch (error) {
    table = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
    Logger.log('Table created: %s', table.id);
  }

  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  // This represents ALL the data
  var rows = file.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rowsCSV = rows.join("\n");
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(rowsCSV, "text/csv");
  var data = blob.setContentType('application/octet-stream');
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        },
        skipLeadingRows: 1,
        writeDisposition: writeDispositionSetting
      }
    }
  };

  var runJob = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
  Logger.log(runJob.status);
  var jobId = runJob.jobReference.jobId
  Logger.log('jobId: ' + jobId);
  var status = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId);

  while (status.status.state === 'RUNNING') {
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    status = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId);
    Logger.log('Status: ' + status);
  }
  Logger.log('FINNISHED!');
  }
```

Comment: Do you see a JOBID being created? See in BigQuery UI for all users of your project.

Comment: What if you add TWO rows?

Comment: I have tried your script and worked fine retrieving and inserting more than 10 000 rows in test Spreadsheet. Could you provide some error message, screenshot  or anything useful to help troubleshooting.

Comment: I checked the job history in BigQuery and found an error with the format of the data on one row when I included all data. So now it works. Thanks a lot for all the responses and support.